# Python: how to convert every beginning and end of string by double quote and next remove or replace double inside by single?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings like this:

```
[ "sentence_1", 'sentence_2 of "me"']
```

I would like to have this:

```
[ "sentence_1", "sentence_2 of 'me'"]
```

or:

```
[ "sentence_1", "sentence_2 of me"]
```

I tried regex but doesn't work:

```
for i in list:
    i.replace({'"':''}, regex=True).replace({"'":' '}, regex=True)
```

I don't know how to solve it

Comment: No need for regex. You're not assigning the result of `str.replace()`. Strings are immutable; the `str.replace()` method returns a new `str` object and you're not doing anything with that returned string.

Comment: Are the beginning/ending quotes actually part of the string?

Comment: @john-gordon the beginning/ending quotes are not part of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the quotes completely you can do

```py
mylist = [ "sentence_1", 'sentence_2 of "me"']
[x.replace('"', '').replace("'", '') for x in mylist]
```

which uses a list comprehension to remove all single and double quotes and results in

```py
['sentence_1', 'sentence_2 of me']
```

If you want to replace all double quotes with single quotes,

```py
[x.replace('"', "'") for x in mylist]
```

will return

```py
['sentence_1', "sentence_2 of 'me'"]
```